# Click counter when link is clicked PHP/JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, click-counting

I have a little script here that counts clicks when link is clicked and stores it in .txt file, but it works fine when I have only "click=yes" under href. But I can't make it to track clicks when I have link to external site.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(!file_exists('counter.txt')){
file_put_contents('counter.txt', '0');
}
if($_GET['click'] == 'yes'){
file_put_contents('counter.txt', ((int) file_get_contents('counter.txt')) + 1);
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
die;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>counter example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo file_get_contents('counter.txt'); ?></h1>
<a href="http://www.google.com?click=yes" target="new">clickMe</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My guess is it has to do something with header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); but I can't figure it out so I could really use some help.

And is it somehow possible to have multiple links save to the same file, and when I show it on website it's sorted from largest number to smallest? I have an idea how to do it with MySQL database but I can't use it at place where this will be implemented.

Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: would need to use javascript to intercept click event and send data by ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server never sees the *URI* being accessed as the client leaves your page. To do something like this, it may be best to set up a redirect which works like this

```html
<a href="/goto.php?href=http://www.google.com" target="_blank">click me</a>
```

(Make sure the external site's URL is *URL encoded* as you're passing it as a GET component of a *URL* to your own page)

Then in `goto.php` you store your click and send a redirect header

```php
if(!file_exists('counter.txt')){
    file_put_contents('counter.txt', '0');
}
file_put_contents('counter.txt', ((int) file_get_contents('counter.txt')) + 1);
header('Location: ' . $_GET['href']);
```

---

Now you can track these clicks, you can add your domain-specific counters in `goto.php` instead of your text file

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or what but it's not working. I did as you said, I made goto.php and put that code in it and my href has the link as in this post but it doesn't opetn external website and the counter does not increase numbers.

Comment: You've described perfectly well what isn't happening when you've attempted this, but you've not described what is happening. Is it giving a `404`? This suggests that it's looking for `goto.php` in a different place to where you saved it (I assumed it'd be in the root of your domain)

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes it's giving me 404. And goto.php is in the same place as my counter.php

Comment: Nevermind me, and triplechecked it and I had an extra letter in the link. Sorry. And thx a lot for the effort.

Comment: I began the _href_ with a `/` - this means it points to `the root of the domain. Remove that slash and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javascript to catch click on a link , send data via AJAX call. Here is small sample using JQuery.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(
                    function() {
                        $('a').click(linkClicked);
                    }
            );
            //this funciton will be called on every click on any link on page
            function linkClicked() {
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                //call PHP script to save URL ./saveurlclicks.php?url=CLICKEDURL
                $.get('./saveurlclicks.php', {'url': url})
                //be sure to return true so user can navigate further
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href='/some href' >asasa</a>

        <a href="www.google.com" >google</a>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
//saveurlclicks.php
// here we save links in file but using serialized array
// if you need to get count of links clicked , 
// have a second script that unserializes array and sort it in revers order 
$url = @$_GET['url'];
$counterFile = 'counter.ser';
if ($url) {
    if(file_exist($filename))
    $links = unserialize(file_get_contents($filename));
    else $links=array();

    if (!isset($links[$url])) {
        $links[$url] = 0;
    }
    $links[$url] ++;
    file_put_contents($counterFile, serialize($links));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I love the simple solution by Paul S., but if you want to track the clicks with date, you can do something like this:

> 03/03/2022    14 
> 04/03/2022    2

```
    <?php
$dateexists = false;

if(!file_exists('counter.txt'))
    { $fh = fopen('counter.txt', 'w');
      fclose($fh); }

$datecounts = file('counter.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($datecounts as $key => $datecount){

list($date, $count) = explode("\t", $datecount);

$count = (int) $count;
if($date == date('d/m/Y'))
{   $datecounts[$key] = $date."\t".++$count;
    $dateexists = true; }
}
if(!$dateexists)
    { $datecounts[] = date('d/m/Y')."\t1"; }

$fh = fopen('counter.txt', 'w');
if (flock($fh, LOCK_EX)) {
    foreach($datecounts as $datecount)
    { fwrite($fh, $datecount.PHP_EOL); }
flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
}

else
{ //couldn't lock, might want to do stuff here }

fclose($fh);
header('Location: ' . $_GET['href']); // the redirect
?>
```