# Url click counter, only registering one unique click counter from one browser

Tags: javascript, html, click, unique, counter

I want to make my post url to update the total click by registering it one unique click per browser everytime it is(the url) clicked, in simpler words, i want my total clicks to be unique.

I have found the method for url clicking here

http://jsfiddle.net/donejs/qYdwR/

```
//html    

<!-- YOUR CODE HERE -->
<div id="content"></div>

<!-- PUT ANY TEMPLATES YOU NEED HERE -->
<script id="main-template" type="text/mustache">
    <h2>CanJS component example</h2>
    <click-counter></click-counter>
</script>

//javascript

var Component = can.Component.extend({
    tag: 'click-counter',
    template: '<a href="javascript://" can-click="updateCount">' +
            'Click Me</a>' +
            '<p id="msg">Clicked {{count}} times</p>',
    scope: {
        count: 0,
        updateCount: function() {
            this.attr('count', this.attr('count') + 1);
        }
    }
});

$('#content').html(can.view('main-template', {}));
```

The example of what i wish to do can be seen here [pingje.org](http://www.pingje.org/) (article post).

Help me gurus, point me where to start, ive been trying to achieve this for days now, any time you took to answer my question is highly appreciated.

Comment: unclear what the problem is, please explain your goal more.

Comment: This is what i want to achieve : **When the post url is clicked(number 1), the hits increases uniquely per user (number 2)**
the visual example can be seen here : http://imgur.com/CnFb2zi @dandavis

Comment: that seems to be what is happening right now; every user has a unique count because the number only exists in the browser, not on a server where more than one machine can see it.

Comment: Yes, in pingje.org it is correctly implemented, i wanted to study/know/identify the method used to implement in my website which is pinglah.org . @dandavis

Comment: is the method is same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087296/click-counter-when-link-is-clicked-php-js im not sure.